# Detecting equivalent classes with python

Tags: python, list, class, partitioning, equivalent

If two lists of numbers are given, what is the quick(est) way to detect equivalent classes.

In the case of lists `list1 = [1,1,2,3,3,4]` and `list2 = [5,6,7,7,8,6]` there
should be two equivalent classes: `eqClasses = [[1,4,5,6],[2,3,7,8]]`.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent class? What's the equivalence relation?

Comment: In my case, you may think about it (equivalent class) as sets/lists of related numbers. More precisely, these two lists (list1 and list2) represents numbers that are related. So, 1 is related to 5 and 6, 2 is related to 7, 3 is related to 7 and 8 and 4 is related to 6. And results are lists of numbers that are related to each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [union-find or disjoint set algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) for this. (I always have an implementation nearby as it's so useful.) Just "union" the different pairs of zipped numbers and then get the "groups" as those numbers that have the same "leader".

Problem-independent implementation:

```
class UnionFind:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leaders = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)

    def find(self, x):
        l = self.leaders[x]
        if l is not None:
            l = self.find(l)
            self.leaders[x] = l
            return l
        return x

    def union(self, x, y):
        lx, ly = self.find(x), self.find(y)
        if lx != ly:
            self.leaders[lx] = ly

    def get_groups(self):
        groups = collections.defaultdict(set)
        for x in self.leaders:
            groups[self.find(x)].add(x)
        return list(groups.values())
```

Application:

```
list1 = [1,1,2,3,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7,7,8,6]

uf = UnionFind()
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    uf.union(a, b)

print(uf.get_groups())
# [{8, 2, 3, 7}, {1, 4, 5, 6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, two elements are equivalent, if they appear in both arrays at the same position.

If you reformulate the problem, it comes down to *finding connected subgraphs*. You can transform the two lists into a list of pairs of equivalent numbers. Each number can be viewed as a vertex in a graph and each pair defines edges  between them. A simple breadth or depth first search can be used to find connected subgraphs. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) says:

> In either case, a search that begins at some particular vertex v will find the entire connected component containing v (and no more) before returning. To find all the connected components of a graph, loop through its vertices, starting a new breadth first or depth first search whenever the loop reaches a vertex that has not already been included in a previously found connected component.

If you need a practical solution, there are packages available which provide these algorithms. Have a look at [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, sauerburger! Unfortunately, if to try your algorithm with the following input, it does not work correctly:
list1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5] and 
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,8,10,6]. 
Correct answer is [[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11], [2, 4, 8, 9, 12]]

Comment: Good point. I completely missed this. I have updated the answer.